# How to set payment_method_nonce

Tags: php, braintree

I am new to Braintree and I am having hard time figuring out how to setup the payment_method_nonce, so that I can submit the transaction.

Trying to combine it with PHP, as a back-end.

dropin form:

```
<form action="charge.php" method="post" id="payment-form" >
    <input id="nonce" name="payment_method_nonce" type="hidden" />
    <div id="dropin-container"></div>
    <button id="submit-button">Submit</button>
</form>
```

dropin js:

```
var button = document.querySelector('#submit-button');

        braintree.dropin.create({
        authorization: 'MyClientToken',
          container: '#dropin-container'
        }, function (createErr, instance) {
          button.addEventListener('click', function () {
            instance.requestPaymentMethod(function (requestPaymentMethodErr, payload) {

            });
          });
        });
```

php:

```
require_once('vendor/autoload.php'); 

    $POST = filter_var_array($_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $nonceFromTheClient = $POST['payment_method_nonce'];

    $gateway = new Braintree_Gateway([
        'environment' => 'sandbox',
        'merchantId' => 'sdfsdh8s9d8f2mpf',
        'publicKey' => 'dp9t6dnc53mcge6s7',
        'privateKey' => 'shd6vnf7dmr7sl904mcte64nf63nf67s'
    ]);

    $clientToken = $gateway->clientToken()->generate();

    $result = $gateway->transaction()->sale([
      'amount' => '50.00',
      'paymentMethodNonce' => $nonceFromTheClient,
      'options' => [
        'submitForSettlement' => True
      ]
    ]);
```

Comment: It's set during the form's submit and given back before the form submits. So you get it from the payload and put it in your input, then allow the form to finish submitting or run an async to do it and block submit.

Comment: Thank you! I got it now.